# Python Selenium Create List Of li

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to load li elements into a list using Python Selenium, my HTML is...

```
<form name="MyForm" class="form_class">
    <div class="form_inner">
        <ul class="form_inner_fields">
            <li class="form_item">Option 1</li>
            <li class="form_item">Option 2</li>
            <li class="form_item">Option 3</li>
            <li class="form_item">Option 4</li>
            <li class="form_item">Option 5</li>
            <li class="form_item">Option 6</li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</form>
```

And Python code is...

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".form_inner_fields li")
list_of_links = [[link.text] for link in links]

for item in list_of_links:
    print (link)
```

This is correctly identifying the 6 options but the list it creates looks like this...

```
<class 'link'>
<class 'link'>
<class 'link'>
<class 'link'>
<class 'link'>
<class 'link'>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok using Xpath - Use this

```
for single_List_Item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='form_inner_fields']/li"): 
    print single_List_Item.text
```